# How To Build a Webcam Recorder App in Node.js With Express as the Backend and React as the Frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, video-streaming

I am trying to build a Surveillance-Video-Recorder-like app that can stream and record multiple real-time videos from various USB cameras connected to a computer. I am looking for an approach where I use NodeJs with Express, Socket.io, and either OpenCV, FFMPEG, or WebRTC to stream, record, store, and transfer the videos in the server side while using React as the Frontend. I managed to build a camera streamer and recorder using WebRTC in React (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) but I am looking for way to manage the streaming, recording, and transferring of blobs from the server side. Any directions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.